# How to retrieve an XML string from a POST RequestBody in Swagger-generated Spring server code?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, swagger-editor

I want to create a REST API method that receives an XML string sent by POST. I'm using [Swagger Editor](http://editor.swagger.io/#/) to design my REST API top-down and to generate the server stub code.

The POST method looks like this in my `swagger.yaml`:

```
  /models:
    post:
      summary: Store a model.
      description: Stores the XML content of the specified model.
      consumes:
        - application/xml;charset=UTF-8
      parameters:
        - name: model
          in: body
          description: The model XML you want to store
          schema:
            type: string
          required: true
      responses:
        201:
          description: Model stored successfully
          headers:
            location:
              description: URL of the stored model.
              type: string
```

I also have this global setting in the yaml file:

```
produces:
  - application/json
```

When I use the Swagger Editor's *Generate Server > Spring* menu option the following interface method is generated for the POST method:

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "Store a model.", notes = "Stores the XML content of the specified model.", response = Void.class, tags={  })
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
        @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "Model stored successfully", response = Void.class) })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/models",
        produces = { "application/json" }, 
        consumes = { "application/xml;charset=UTF-8" },
        method = RequestMethod.POST)
    ResponseEntity<Void> modelsPost(

@ApiParam(value = "The model XML you want to store" ,required=true ) @RequestBody String model);
```

and this is the corresponding stub implementation:

```
    public ResponseEntity<Void> modelsPost(
@ApiParam(value = "The model XML you want to store" ,required=true ) @RequestBody String model

) {
        // do some magic!
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I use Postman to post some dummy XML to the method on my running Springboot service:

[image: Postman screenshot]

But when I print out the value of `model` inside the implementation method with `log.debug("Model XML = " + model);` I get output like this in the logs:

```
Model XML = ------WebKitFormBoundaryA3o70hOgLFoLLBoY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="model"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Hello></Hello>
------WebKitFormBoundaryA3o70hOgLFoLLBoY--
```

How do I get just the XML itself into the value of `model`?  I want it to be this instead in this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Hello></Hello>
```

Remember I can't just edit the Java method signatures directly because the Swagger Editor is generating them. If my swagger definition is wrong what should I be using instead to post an XML string?

The XML in practice is likely to be large so sending it as a request parameter is not an option. I'm also not going to process the XML so it's ok to treat it as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In postman, switch from form-data to raw, and select the relevant content-type (application/xml).

You have to do this because spring is expecting your object to be in the request body (because of `@RequestBody` annotation on your parameter)

Comment: Thanks - that worked! All I had to do was put `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Hello></Hello>` in the raw field and that's what was received by the service. So the parameter `model` was redundant.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the bare minimum converters and want to read the Json/XML as string, you will also need a converter to convert the content-type to string. StringHttpMessageConverter does just that.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven
    content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager">
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="false">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                <list>
                    <value>application/json</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
            <constructor-arg ref="jaxbMarshaller" />
            <constructor-arg ref="jaxbUnMarshaller" />
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                <list>
                    <value>application/xml</value>
                    <value>text/xml</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                <list>
                    <value>text/plain</value>
                    <value>application/xml</value> <!-- extract xml as string -->
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="writeAcceptCharset" value="true" />
        </bean>
```